# Do you think this question could be a trick to get traffic to their site?

Tags: discussion

[Here is the question in question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651689/only-my-company-website-wont-open-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

At first glance this seems ok but on reflection it could be well disguised spam.

It is strange only their site won't work and every user who sees the question would need to visit the site (which works fine in 14.04 and firefox) to verify it.

I was going to leave it but based on a comment that seem suspicious of the question by @Bruni and seeing the down votes, should this be flagged?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could've sworn I read something similar to this before in the past.  And I could have sworn it was "spam".

I ran this site in Tor Browser, in Permissive (to a point) mode.  It did not fail to load and I have 14.04.

I'm not 100% certain, but it 'reads' as spam to me, as they fail to explain exactly what they DO see before a crash, and no responses to inquiries.  If there's no other comments on it from OP i'd flag it as suspicious.